# Array of funcs in a Swift class instance

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I get an array of funcs prefixed with a certain name from a Swift class instance without hardcoding those funcs' names?

e.g.

```
class Dialog {
  init() {

  }

  func stepOne(session: Session) {
    ...
  }

  func stepTwo(session: Session) {
    ...
  }

  func stepThree(session: Session) {
    ...
  }

  func someOtherFunc() {
    ...
  }

  func steps() -> [(Session) -> Void] {
    // should return [stepOne, stepTwo, stepThree];
  }
}
```

Comment: Swift itself doesn't have that kind of reflection ability, you'd have to delve into the Obj-C runtime (but even then, I don't believe you'll have any guarantee of the order of the functions). But all of this seems like very brittle design (what if you added a `stepsRemaining` property? the synthesised Obj-C getter selector would have a prefix of "step") – I really don't see what's wrong with specifying an array.

Answer (score 0):

The functions have to come from somewhere. They don't necessarily have to be defined in `Dialog`; they can be local variables inside `func steps()`. For instance:

```
func steps() -> [(Session) -> Void] {
    var allSteps: [(Session) -> Void] = []
    for i in 0..<3 {
        let currentStep: (Session) -> Void = { session in 
            print("Executing step \(i)")
        }
        allSteps.append(currentStep)
    }
    return allSteps
}
```

Comment: I was hoping not to have to have an allSteps variable holding these. I want something similar to XCTest, where it will run all funcs prefixed with test. I just want the array of funcs instead.

Comment: Ah, so you want to programmatically find all functions in a class with the right signature (ie `(Session) -> Void`)?

Comment: That's a fair bit trickier, and something I don't know a lot about, but the topic you're looking for is "Reflection", and Swift's `Mirror` class: https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/